# How to find out if filter functions work with half-amplitude or half-power cut-offs

Tags: python, scipy, filtering, signal-processing

I used [`scipy.signal.firwin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html) to filter a signal that I have. Now I want to report the cutoff frequency used, however the documentation is not clear on these points:

- How is the cutoff frequency specified? As half-power(-3dB) or half-amplitude(-6dB)? ...
- Where is the cutoff frequency "located"? In the middle of transition band? At the edge between passband and transition band? ...

In my case, knowing about the speficis of `scipy.signal.firwin` would already be helpful. But a bonus answer would be to show how I can computationally find out about this (or maybe through plotting?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fc` is the *desired* half-amplitude frequency.  In the actual filter designed by `firwin`, the gain at `fc` will be approximately 0.5, with the approximation improving as the number of taps is increased.

Here's a plot that shows the frequency responses of several lowpass filters designed with `firwin` and a few different windows.  The script that generates the plot is below.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import firwin, freqz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Desired half-amplitude cutoff
fc = 0.2

# Length of the FIR filter
numtaps = 51

windows = ['boxcar', 'hann', 'hamming', 'blackman']

for window in windows:
    taps = firwin(numtaps, fc, window=window, scale=False)
    w, h = freqz(taps, worN=8000)

    plt.plot(w/np.pi, np.abs(h), label=window)

plt.legend(title='Window Function', loc='best', framealpha=1, shadow=True)
plt.axhline(0.5, alpha=0.3, color='k', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim(0, 2*fc)
plt.xlabel('Normalized frequency (1 = Nyquist)')
plt.ylabel('Gain')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The window method is a heuristic to approximate the frequency response of an ideal (brickwall) filter (with infinite taps). Therefore, the "cutoff" frequency corresponds to the cutoff frequency of the ideal filter you try to approximate (the notion of half-power/amplitude cutoff make no sense in the ideal setting). Of course, as the resulting design is only an approximation of the ideal, you will have to examine its frequency response and see if it is sufficient for your needs.